# Migrate from Encryption trait to Laravel model $cast

Tags: laravel, encryption, eloquent, casting

I'm trying to migrate the following [trait](https://github.com/betterapp/laravel-db-encrypter/blob/master/src/Traits/EncryptableDbAttribute.php) that I used to encrypt certain columns in my DB to the native Laravel 9 encrypted cast.

The problem I'm getting is that, although it works great for new values, for existing values I'm getting some extra values.

So instead of getting a clean value after decryption:

```
Harry Potter
```

I'm getting the following:

```
s:23:"Harry Potter";
```

And I'm not sure what's the best way to proceed? I was thinking about looping through all the values and applying some RegEx, but it's crazy, I have a lot of columns and values by now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't already have mixed encrypted values with the two different methods :

One solution could be to comment the encryptable attribute in your models(the one of the custom trait) then write code that re-saves all your models that have encrypted values (this should save the columns decrypted).

At this point you'd remove the custom trait from your project and add the Laravel 9 encrypted cast in your models and write code to re-save everything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should run a migration to encrypt the values. For example:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class EncryptUserEmailInUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        DB::table('users')->where('user_email', '!=', null)
            ->select(['id','user_email'])
            ->get()
            ->each(function($z) {
                DB::table('users')->where('id', $z->id)
                    ->update([
                        'user_email' => Crypt::encryptString($z->user_email)
                    ]);
            });
    }
}
```